# Pandas: Conditionally append data to column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames that I need to merge.

In `n_df` there are several columns, but the ones that are relevant are:

```
Statement     Codes
Statement 1   CD.Ex-1
Statement 2   CD.Ex-2
Statement 3   CD.Ex-3
Statement 4   CD.Ex-4
Statement 5   CD.Ex-5
```

```
{
    "Statement": ["Statement 1", "Statement 2", "Statement 3",
                  "Statement 4", "Statement 5",],
    "Codes": ["CD.Ex-1", "CD.Ex-2", "CD.Ex-3","CD.Ex-4","CD.Ex-5",],
    ...
}
```

In `p_df` I have 3 columns:

```
Statement     Codes     Other_Codes
Statement A   CD.Ex-A   NC.a
Statement X   CD.Ex-2   NC.b
Statement B   CD.Ex-B   NC.c
Statement 4   CD.Ex-4   NC.d
Statement C   CD.Ex-C   NC.e
```

```
{
    "Statement": ["Statement A", "Statement X", "Statement B",
                  "Statement 4", "Statement C",],
    "Codes": ["CD.Ex-A", "CD.Ex-2", "CD.Ex-B","CD.Ex-4","CD.Ex-C",],
    "Other_Codes": ["NC.a", "NC.b", "NC.c","NC.d","NC.e",],    
}
```

So what I need to do is:

1. Merge the data frames on `Codes`
2. If `Codes` doesn't exist in `n_df` (such as CD.Ex-A), then append `Codes` (p_df) to `Codes` (n_df)
3. If `Codes` doesn't exist in `n_df` (such as CD.Ex-A), then append the associated `Statement`(p_df) to `Statement` (n_df)

So far I've done `new_df = pd.merge(n_df, p_df, how='outer', on='Codes')`. However, there are a few problems with this: I end up with two `Statement` columns. To mitigate this, I did

```
s_df = p_df[['Other_Codes', 'Statement']]
p_df = p_df.drop('Statement', 1)
```

My thinking is that I can do another merge, on `Other_Codes` to add the `Statement` back in? But I haven't been able to successfully do that. I always end up with two `Statement` columns.

The other issue (probably related) is that the "Statements" from each table don't necessarily align. In my example above, the Statement for Code CD.Ex-2  is `Statement 2` in `n_df` and `Statement X` in `p_df`. If there's a conflict in the Statements, I need n_df to take precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to update values from `Statement (p_df)` to `Statement (n_df)`. Values will be update only if n_df values are NaN.

```
out = n_df.merge(p_df, on='Codes', how='outer', suffixes=('', '_'))
out = out.assign(Statement=out['Statement'].combine_first(out['Statement_'])) \
         .drop(columns='Statement_')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Statement    Codes Other_Codes
0       1.0  CD.Ex-1         NaN
1       2.0  CD.Ex-2        NC.b
2       3.0  CD.Ex-3         NaN
3       4.0  CD.Ex-4        NC.d
4       5.0  CD.Ex-5         NaN
5         A  CD.Ex-A        NC.a
6         B  CD.Ex-B        NC.c
7         C  CD.Ex-C        NC.e
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.